# jQuery onclick load randomly working with firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a few "boxes" with an `onclick` function:

```
<div class="box" onclick="load(1);return false;"></div>
<div class="box" onclick="load(2);return false;"></div>
```

The onclick functions trigger a function that reads the content of a few seperate .php files (example1.php and example2.php).
These files contain other boxes made with fieldset instead of a div.

```
function load(num){ 
$("#loadthis").load("example"+num+".php");
}
```

And the function above is changing the content of this div down here:

```
<div id="loadthis">Load my fieldset boxes</div>
```

So far everything works, until I click on the fieldset boxes.

The background color of the fieldset should change when I click it and the radio inside the fieldset should be selected too (because of css styling), but both of this does not happen. But I can still select the radio when clicking the radio (not the box).

I have tested it in IE and in Chrome, this code works there most of the time.
But in firefox I cannot select the fieldset box 50% of the time.

I tried to experiment with the .on( class but it gives me the same effect.

```
$('fieldset.type-a').children('.row').children('.box.col-4').on("click", load);
function load(){
var index = $('fieldset.type-a').children('.row').children('.box.col-4').index( this );
index+=1;
$("#loadthis").load("fs"+index+".php"); 
}
```

Okay so after some searching I found that there is already an onclick function in a different .js file that being called:

```
 function handleStep2() {
  $('.step-form-2 input[type=radio]').change(function () {
    $(this).closest('fieldset').find('.box').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.box').addClass('active');
    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
 });

 $('.step-form-2 .select-box .box').click(function () {
   $(this).find('input[type=radio]').trigger('change');
 });
 }
```

I am now going to try to merge the codes and see if that gets rid of the bug with the active class not being activated on click.

**SOLVED:** I solved it by indeed merging both the codes to 1 click function. Thanks for all your help guys, But I still wonder if this could be done a different way?

Comment: Your description is well written, but the scenario is a bit too complicated to follow. I suggest creating an example scenario over at [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net), saving it, and posting the URL in your question. That will allow us answerers to better understand the problem and give us an environment in which to experiment with solutions.

Comment: so... the boxes loaded dynamically don't respond to jquery call? you prob should try  $('body').on('click', '#loadthis', function() {});

Comment: 'Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.' jquery documentation

Comment: Provide and example on jsFiddle or codepen that we can validate in these browsers

Comment: What happens if you hard code the output of a php file (fieldset) in #loadthis ? Does that work properly? Can you show that in fiddle? Because from current fiddle its not clear what is the expected behavior or the issue that you are facing.

Comment: @VivekAthalye If I hardcode the fieldset, it doesn't work, because the load function doesn't work that way, but I have tried this same thing with the show and hide function where I put all the fieldset boxes in the index.php and hide them all, until the div box is clicked, but I don't like this, because it doesn't look smooth.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you to hard code it in real system. I'm suggesting to hard code it in fiddle so that people will understand your problem. :)

Comment: I don't know how I should do this, since the load function takes the data from my server, I've tried to put the full link there, but it doesn't work, because I think the function only works on local files? I can hardcode it with a different function, but that will not display my problem. I already put a style for the fieldset, so you can make 2 files (example1.php and example2.php) and try to call them with the load function (by clicking the div boxes). The only thing you should include in the 2 example.php files is <fieldset></fieldset> if I am correct.

Comment: I don't think there is any issue with load(). What is the **output** of php file, put that inside #loadthis div (in fiddle) and show us the issue that you are talking about (radio button, background color etc). Your current code doesn't show anything about the problem that you are describing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have changed the fiddles to give you guys more content, however the fiddle doesn't work for me now, might be because of missing JS files. If you guys can't see what I am doing wrong here, but want to help me, I can give you the link to my website. Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem. Rather than adding “solved” to the title, please mark the answer that solved the problem as accepted — that's how we do things here. (If none of the answers posted by other people solved your problem, you can post yours.) For more information, see [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Look into event delegation, and if you're using jQuery it's easy

look into the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for `.on(`

Also you want to make sure you're using unobtrusive JS, so pull that out of your HTML, put it in a `.js` file as an event listener and load the script after the DOM has loaded as the last thing before your closing `</body>` tag

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. The documentation of the .on( function is pretty nice. If I get it correctly: I can put this code in a JS file and it checks if the div was clicked? Also is this Firefox issue a known issue and do you think this should change it.

Comment: Sort of. What actually is happening as that it's watching the parent element if a child element is clicked. There is no "issue" per se, its just that there is no event watcher attached to the new elements that have been dynamically loaded. Also, every time you run: `handleStep2()` you're creating additional event listeners and you end up with double and tripple events , and so on every time it gets run... put yourself a bunch of `console.log( 'step *' )` the `*` of course being the step #, or function location you're watching for, and see how many times everything gets run.

Comment: the `.on(` method (it's called a method, not a class) is a delegate event listener, so you don't need a new event when dynamic elements are created inside the parent. This means you only need to attach a single event run once, not every time new DOM elements are added to the page. Hope this helps, Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a delay about loading php files content.
Is it work when you click one of them even takes time?

Maybe you should [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)  for loading php files. By the way you can send data to php files using GET or POST methods.

You can check [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples) examples.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.
It doesn't matter how long I wait, the loaded content will not change onclick.
I could try to get the data with the GET or POST methods, but I wonder how I should do that, because the content is pretty big and the amount of fieldset boxes can vary from file to file and I want to have css styling on it (which is included in the original file).

Answer (score 0):

If your function is initalized in an IIFE, inline js can´t access this function.
It´s weird that you say this sometimes works..

IIFE is a wrapper function to create capsules, so the client can´t modify your script in runtime. 
Looks like this:

```
(function(){
 /* code */ 
}());
```

It would be much better to create js-events:

```
on('body', 'click', '.box', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target); // this is the clicked list item
});
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but I already tried the on( function and it gave me the same result, probably because there was already a click function for that div as you can read in my edited post.